# ASP.NET CORE WebApi message consuming performance issue with RabbitMQ

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I'm using the .net client for rabbitMQ in my asp.net core webApi. I'm connecting to an exchange, declaring a queue and then start consuming it through a channel. The problem here is that when I publish a "large" number of messages at the same time to this specific queue, the consuming performance stays very low (4 messages per second, approximately).

I already searched for some configurations that could improve the consuming performance but none of them was actually effective and I'm starting to think that maybe I misunderstood the correct use of rabbitMQ on this case. I tried to increase the number of opened channels and consumer instances and it improved a little bit but nothing close to what I expected from rabbitMQ. I also tried to increase the prefetch quantity but got no explicit improvements on that.

Here is my piece of code responsible for the consumption (before my modifications to improve the performance):

```
public void Receive(string hostName, string queueName, string type, string routingKey, string exchange)
{
    //RabbitMQ configuration
    var userName = _configuration["Messaging:UserName"];
    var password = _configuration["Messaging:Password"];
    var prefetchQuantity = _configuration["Messaging:PrefetchQuantity"];

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, UserName = userName, Password = password };
    var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

    var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    channel.BasicQos(0, Convert.ToUInt16(prefetchQuantity), false);

    //Declaring the exchange
    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange, ExchangeType.Direct);

    //Declaring the queue and creating its routing key bindings
    channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

    channel.QueueBind(queueName, exchange, routingKey);

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

    consumer.Received += (model, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            mediatorHandler.Handle(model, e, _mediator);

            channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
            channel.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, false, true);
        }
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
        autoAck: false,
        consumer: consumer);
}
```

After the modifications (more channels, more consumers and prefetch count):

```
public void Receive(string hostName, string queueName, string type, IEnumerable<string> routingKeys, string exchange)
{
    //Initializes the MediatorHandler`s factory
    InitializeFactory();

    var mediatorHandler = _mediatorHandlers[type];

    //RabbitMQ configuration
    var userName = _configuration["Messaging:UserName"];
    var password = _configuration["Messaging:Password"];
    var numberOfConsumers = int.Parse(_configuration["Messaging:NumerOfConsumers"]);
    var channels = int.Parse(_configuration["Messaging:Channels"]);

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, UserName = userName, Password = password };

    var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

    for (int i = 1; i <= channels; i++)
    {
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        var prefetchQuantity = _configuration["Messaging:PrefetchQuantity"];

        channel.BasicQos(0, Convert.ToUInt16(prefetchQuantity), false);

        //Declaring the exchange
        channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange, ExchangeType.Direct);

        //Declaring the queue and creating its routing key bindings
        channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

        foreach (var routingKey in routingKeys)
        {
            channel.QueueBind(queueName, exchange, routingKey);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfConsumers; j++)
        {
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += (model, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    mediatorHandler.Handle(model, e, _mediator);

                    channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    channel.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                }
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                autoAck: false,
                consumer: consumer);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve the consuming performance in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your `mediatorHandler.Handle` doing? What happens when you fill the queue first and just consume/ack messages without invoking `Handle` method?